# C function read() leads to command injection

Tags: c, shell

I have this kind of C code, and after first input, if I enter a big string, finally the latter characters are executed as command in my Linux Shell, which can be used for command injection, as I've found read() function is a main reason why this happens, but don't understand why, `val` is just an int:

```
if (val > 0) {

    struct in_addr *addr;
    int addrMultVal = val*sizeof(*addr);
    char *buf2 = malloc(addrMultVal);
    for (i = 0; i < val; i++) {             
        if (read(0, buf2, sizeof(*addr)) < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    done = 1;
}
```

Comment: `int addrMultVal = val*sizeof(addr);` should be `int addrMultVal = val*sizeof(*addr);`

Comment: @LPs it says that: error: ‘in_addr’ undeclared

Comment: You're referring to `sizeof(*addr)` later, so the expression should be ok. Can you just edit your question to show exactly what your code looks like after the change?

Comment: Oh, and also: you should check the return value of malloc, and you're only using the first in_addr of your allocated array.

Comment: I'm not gettig you. How in_addr is related to the big string? What's the problem: could you explain it deeply?

Comment: @LPs I get user input with read(0, buf2, sizeof(*addr)) function, so if user enters a big string it causes this problem.

Comment: @Useless thanks, checking malloc() returning value looks to be a right way.

Comment: @Shota Ok. Do you mean  read(STDIN_FILENO, buf2, sizeof(*addr));`?

Comment: @LPs yes first 0 parameter means stdin

Comment: @LPs you will need to include whatever header defines the `struct in_addr` struct that you are trying to use

Comment: What do you mean by *"finally the latter characters are executed as command in my Linux Shell"*? The shell executes the rest of the input after your program exits? This is not injection at all and it's also not a security issue. Since you are able to launch your program from the command line, obviously you can issue other commands to the interpreter.

Comment: @axiac yes shell is executing the leftover data.

Comment: So your problem is just that the program doesn't drain stdin? Just tack a non-blocking read on the end and drain it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addrMultVal` variable has to count the size of the type of addr, then you have to `sizeof(*addr)`

Your code, `sizeof(addr)`, is returning you the size of pointer, that is probably 4.

Take also note that `read()` doesn't add `'\0'` to terminate to make it string (just gives raw buffer).

Comment: Thanks, should be that way, but command injection still happens.